# observable is not allowing to access instance member variables

Tags: angular

here in hotelService i am fetching data from backend api which contain the hotel data
**hotelService** file

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from "@angular/common/http";
import { HotelModel } from "./hotel.model";
import {Observable, of} from "rxjs/index";
import { catchError, map, tap } from "rxjs/internal/operators";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HotelService {
  private hotelsUrl = 'api/hotels';  // URL to web api

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };

  getHotels(): Observable<HotelModel[]>{
    return this.http.get<HotelModel[]>(this.hotelsUrl).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError<HotelModel[]>('getHotels', []))
    )
  }

  getHotel(id:number): Observable<HotelModel>{
    const url = `${this.hotelsUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<HotelModel>(url).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError<HotelModel>('getHotel id=${id}'))
    )
  }

  updateHotel(hotel:HotelModel): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.put<HotelModel>(this.hotelsUrl, hotel, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError<any>('updateHotel'))
    )
  }

  deleteHotel(hotel:HotelModel):Observable<any>{
    const id = typeof hotel === 'number' ? hotel : hotel.id;
    const url = `${this.hotelsUrl}/${id}`;

    return this.http.delete<HotelModel>(url, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError<HotelModel>('deleteHero'))
    )
  }







  private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
  return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
    console.error(error); // log to console instead
    return of(result as T);
    };
  }


}
```

**hotelEditComponent**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
import { Location } from "@angular/common";
import { HotelService } from "../hotel.service";
import { HotelModel } from "../hotel.model";
import {ActivatedRoute, Params} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hotel-edit',
  templateUrl: './hotel-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hotel-edit.component.css']
})
export class HotelEditComponent implements OnInit {

  id: number;
  editMode = false;
  hotelEditForm;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private hotelService: HotelService,
    private location: Location,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,

    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // const urlId = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    // this.id = urlId;
    // console.log(this.id);


    this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params: Params) => {
        this.id = +params['id'];
        this.editMode = params['id'] != null;
        this.initForm()

      }
    );

  }


  private initForm(){
    let HotelName = '';
    let HotelImagePath = '';
    let HotelPrice = '';
    let HotelDescription = '';
    let HotelAddress = '';

    if(this.editMode){
      const hotel = this.hotelService.getHotel(this.id);
      console.log(hotel);
      HotelName = hotel.name;
      HotelImagePath = hotel.imagePath;
      HotelPrice = hotel.price;
      HotelDescription = hotel.description;
      HotelAddress = hotel.address;


    }

    this.hotelEditForm = this.fb.group({
    name: [HotelName],
    imagePath:[HotelImagePath],
    price:[HotelPrice],
    description:[HotelDescription],
    address:[HotelAddress],

  });

  }


  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.hotelEditForm)

  }



}
```

the error is in initForm() method the variable hotel getting the single hotel using id in form of observable when i am trying to access hotel.name, hotel.price, hotel.address it shows **unresolved variable name,price, address**
 *what i am doing wrong here?*

```js
 if(this.editMode){
          const hotel = this.hotelService.getHotel(this.id);
          console.log(hotel);
          HotelName = hotel.name;
          HotelImagePath = hotel.imagePath;
          HotelPrice = hotel.price;
          HotelDescription = hotel.description;
          HotelAddress = hotel.address;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly access instance members on `Observable`, you need to subscribe to it and then access it, like:

```
if(this.editMode){
      this.hotelService.getHotel(this.id).subscribe(data => {
           const hotel = data;
           console.log(hotel);
           HotelName = hotel.name;
           HotelImagePath = hotel.imagePath;
           HotelPrice = hotel.price;
           HotelDescription = hotel.description;
           HotelAddress = hotel.address;

           //update: Move formBuilder code inside subscribe as well
           this.hotelEditForm.controls['name'].setValue(HotelName);
           this.hotelEditForm.controls['imagePath'].setValue(HotelImagePath);
           this.hotelEditForm.controls['price'].setValue(HotelPrice);
          this.hotelEditForm.controls['description'].setValue(HotelDescription);
           this.hotelEditForm.controls['address'].setValue(HotelAddress);
        });

 }
```

Comment: thanks @Mustahsan we have to always subscribe the observables to access theirs variables.

Comment: yes, http client always returns the observables not your required data, so you subscribe to it to wait until your real response is provided to you, and then you use that response

Comment: @RahulVerma you're welcome, if it solved your issue, you can consider marking the answer as accepted :)

Comment: one doubt when i am in edit mode like this [link](http://localhost:4200/hotels/0/edit) my form does not prepoppulate with its initial values its shows empty form

Comment: its because your variables are local, set them to class level and bind them using ngModel to your fields, if you can create stackblitz i can help further

Comment: @RahulVerma you need to use `Reactive` form for this purpose, as i can see now you only have a simple html form

Comment: i added ReactiveFormsModule in my modulefile

Comment: see complete example at this link, if you have anymore further queries feel free to ask:
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: i am following the doc only and doing same by using formbuilder and given the formControlName for each name, price,imagePath, description but its not loaded these value in edit mode its only show empty form

Comment: @RahulVerma i have updated the answer please have a look

Comment: getting error  `HotelEditComponent.html:5 ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

       Example:

       
    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

    In your class:

    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    });`

Comment: bro can u take a look here.

Comment: @RahulVerma check this example and let me know if it works https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jh8gc4-kp7gyg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199728/discussion-between-rahul-verma-and-mustahsan).

Comment: bro what it means- assign expression type observable<ObservedValueOf<Observable<Hero[]>>> is not assignable to type Observable<Hero[]>  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jh8gc4 read app.component.html file

Comment: @RahulVerma if you have a new question, please post it as a separate question, so others can help you too